# Seaborn jointplot turn off one of the marginal plots

Tags: python, seaborn

Is there a way to turn off the top marginal plot in a Seaborn Jointplot?

```
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
g = sns.jointplot(
    data=tips,
    x="total_bill",
    y="tip",
    hue="smoker",
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps just call `remove` on `.ax_marg_x`.

```
g.ax_marg_x.remove()
```

Output:

[image]

(Note that `ax_marg_y` and `ax_joint` are the remaining plots, as detailed in the [`JointGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.JointGrid.html#seaborn.JointGrid) docs).

Comment: Thanks! Where would find out that the top plot is accessed through `.ax_marg_x`? I looked at the [docs](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html) but missed it

Comment: While this works, the removed axis still seems to take up figure (white)space, however. Is there any way to change that, i.e., to make the figure as if this axis was never there (or to omit it from the beginning)?

Comment: @EikeP. - per the displayed output, I don't see the whitespace you're referring to?